# how to create new external account with stripe connect PHP?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Hey programmers and etc.

I have never worked with the stripe API before and have therefore encountered an issue.

I am building a platform and it's great but I struggle when customers have to pay the vendors. The code below creates the vendors account in stripe the first time a customer pays the vendor. It works fine without the "external_account" but when I add the "external_account" part it does not work. I've tried to follow the instructions from other posts on stackoverflow but nothing works.

```
$result = \Stripe\Account::create(array(

        "type" => "custom",
        "country" => "DK",


"email" => $currentUserEmail, 

    "legal_entity" => array(

        "first_name" => "Lukas",
        "last_name" => "Mittun", 
        'business_name' => $currentUserEmail,
        'business_tax_id' => '000000000',
        'personal_id_number' => '000000000',

            "dob" => array(
                "day" => 7,
                "month" => 2,
                "year" => 2000
            ),

            "address" => array(
                "city" => "Frederiksberg C",
                "line1" => "Bakkegårds Allé 4 st. th.",
                "postal_code" => "1804"
            ),

        "type" => "individual",

            "verification" => array(
                "document" => null
            )
    ),

    "external_account" => array( 
        "object" => "bank_account",
        "status" => "new",
        "country" => "DK",
        "currency" => "dkk",
        "account" => $result->id,
        "account_holder_name" => 'Lukas Mittun',
        "account_holder_type" => 'individual', 
        "account_number" => "Dk20179012310"

    ),



)); 


      $stripeAccountId = $result->id; 
      $stripeAccountObj = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($stripeAccountId);
      $stripeAccountObj->tos_acceptance->date = time();
      $stripeAccountObj->tos_acceptance->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $stripeAccountObj->save();
```

SOLUTION: don't use live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode

Comment: Not sure, but aren't vendor account for recurring payments? Is that what you want? Could be u need to activate that option in `stripe`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing some parameters that are invalid on `External Account` creation. I'd try to create an external account with the bare minimum amount of information as specified here

https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_bank_account

That would be `country`, `currency`, `account_number` (IBAN), and `object`.

If you try adding this to your `\Stripe\Account::create` call does it work for you?

```
  "external_account" =>  array(
    "country" => "DK",
    "currency" => "DKK",
    "account_number" => "DK89370400440532013000",
    "object" => "bank_account"
  ),
```

Test account number is from https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#payouts